# TypeScript - omit generic's extended type

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, graphql

I have problem with **omit** in typescript. When I am trying omit **commandId** from **TMutationVariables**, it throws TS error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Pick<TMutationVariables, Exclude<keyof TMutationVariables, "commandId">> & { commandId: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TMutationVariables'.   'Pick<TMutationVariables, Exclude<keyof TMutationVariables, "commandId">> & { commandId: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TMutationVariables', but 'TMutationVariables' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ commandId: string; }'.
```

```
export function createQueryWithSubscription<TMutationVariables extends {commandId: string}>(
    query: string,
): (variables: Omit<TMutationVariables, "commandId">) => any {
    const sendQuery = (changes: TMutationVariables): any =>
        gqlCommand<TMutationVariables>(
            query, changes as any
        );

    return function processQueryWithSubscription(
        variables
    ) {
        return async (dispatch: any) => {
            const commandId = generateUuid();
            //error occurs in declaration BELOW
            const completedVariables: TMutationVariables = {
                ...variables,
                commandId
            };
            const commandFinished = await dispatch(sendQuery(completedVariables));
        };
    };
}
```

I have type created from graphql schema (includes commandId to subscription), but from outside I need all variables created from this schema except commandId (because I join commandId in process function).

Live sample:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#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-MFNulcNC3Kh+s8EYcbiAA

Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "extends" in the function signature type

```
export function createQueryWithSubscription<TMutationVariables extends {commandId: string}>(
```

you should merge the declarations like this:

```
type TMutationVariablesWithCommandId = TMutationVariables & {commandId: string};
export function createQueryWithSubscription<TMutationVariablesWithCommandId>(
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoFkCuY5mAexADU4pg4AjAGwgGdkBvAXwG4AoMATwAcUNtcBYqXLU6AdWBgAFgGF8AWwVwQAEwCSq5AF40WHHkIkylGvQBkjBIuVrNALmS0wZEAHNWbCAA9u+KGDIMJggCIYgyAhQELgQAIqY0JySMgDKmBS0UcDc4QA8-AZCxqJmKXI2KhqqAHwAFGwAkACOiVCcjs6ubgA0bACUjnUAbiKmdI4A8gpSBfqCRmNitD3IAETWSlWaazX9OjXIKpyMTdYgzk4QaglJOsh1CNIqbhN6AuEl47SDRyAn2hqTUabmaVHkWzUeWO9WBLTanFWTxedCO9GOwP67Ca0TAmCgEWCoXCyG4UHwSFotFu7XK6Uy2VyQgajUaoxMyya+wYwNx+IicFonFCD1UwFo3FwT0cx32gNOrMa50um1s1XurxA0FiAFVMMBVHUsXDlYFNtwaJBVF9lo5CgthByzPceYrGgA6T3s0p0Ppu1XbVRwzyK02RSpqABioHF0ggWl0cAA7nApMgxRKpdI6rRrqoaZxHooLRArTazP1jayQ54mGwgA)